# Retrieving the image from a folder : Android

Tags: android

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
         {

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder/Raw Image");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
            Date d = new Date();
            CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
            File output = new File(imagesFolder, s.toString() + ".jpg");

            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {
                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();

                Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
                        "Image saved: ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally
            {}
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
File filenew = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Folder/Raw Image");

             bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filenew.getAbsolutePath());
```

Each time when i capture image, the image save to sub folder "Raw Image" which is in a folder " Folder". I need to retrieve this image for further processing. so i used Bitmapfactory.options. All this has to be done under one button click. every image that is saved has to be processed. How can i retrieve in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking photos, what you can do is `startActivityForResult`, during this process you have to work with the `URI`. The `URI` is the path that you have specified for your picture.

And now during your `onActivityResult(..)` call you can do the following:

```
try {
    Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
            activity.getContentResolver(), fileUri);
    photo.setImageBitmap(thumb);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where `fileUri` is the `URI` of the image I was talking about. Here `photo` is the `ImageView`. Also when working with different devices there is a possibility that you may get an error, so I best advice you to save the `URI` path in a `SharedPreference`.

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing to the wrong path :

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"+ Folder + "Raw Image"+ ".jpg";
```

But you have created folder like this,

```
  File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder/Raw Image");
```

Try this way, It may help you.

```
  File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder/RawImage");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 

        File output = new File(imagesFolder,"temp" + ".jpg");
```

Above we have declared a static file name. The file will be replace for every image capture.
Now you know the filepath,

```
String mFilePath =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "Folder/RawImage/temp.jpg";
```

You can use this filepath in the following way to show the bitmap.

```
myImage.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(new File("Your file path")));
Or with:
myImage.setImageUri(Uri.parse(new File("Your file path").toString()));
```

You can get the bitmap :

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Your image URI));
```

Comment: But i dont want to replace it. each time i want to retrieve the captured image to a bitmap with the same name and then i wann process it and want to save the processed image with the same name but into a new folder.. I hope you got my problem

Comment: what ever, You should mention the correct path as well. There is no such file exception will be throw in your code. Please check if the file is exist before using that file. myFile.isExist(); If you are using date,It is hard to find the file name. If you mention the file name you can use appropriately. and you save the image in to the new folder also.